# Django : Customizable templates

Tags: django, templates, user-profile

I am working on creating a web portal and I want to offer the users the feature of making changes to there profile/dashboard like changed background. etc.
Can anybody please guide me to an efficient approach to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is trickery that has more to do with css and javascript than with django templates.

The only thing that is django related here is the actual storing of these preferences.

e.g. the filepaths of the actual background images.

After that you will do something similar to what is described in this answer:

[how to change html background dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194450/how-to-change-html-background-dynamically)

**EDIT**

I don't see why you need different directories for every user. Django templates
give you more than enough power to do what you want.

For example, let's say that each user can upload his own background picture. Also
I assume that you follow this popular django pattern for storing additional information
about your users. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

So we have this `UserProfile` model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('vertical', 'Vertical'),
        ('horizontal', 'Horizontal'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    background_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    dashboard_layout  = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES)
```

You can pass this extra information to your javascript context(either with Ajax or without)
and then change the background image for every individual user.

Also we could do special layout at the template level like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_body %}
    {% if request.user.get_profile.dashboard_layout == 'vertical' %}
        {% include "layouts/vertical.html" %}
    {% else %}
        {% include "layouts/horizontal.html" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock main_body %}
```

Comment: I am thinking of something like creating diff directories(copied from the default template) and assigning them to the users, so that the user-specific templates are displayed from backend. But that would increase server load and use up resources. Anything more efficient would be appreciated.

Comment: @TarunGaba updated my answer. I hope it answers your question more clearly.